# Do I need invoke to access DataGridView.SelectedRows from a async method?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, async-await, invoke

I have a method like this:

```
 async Task foo() {
         foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
         // ...
        }
}
```

called like this:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        foo();
                    });
```

I just noticied that code is acessing `dataGridView1.SelectedRows` directly, without invoke and it's working fine. Am I performing an invalid operation? Is this supposed to work or must I use invoke here?

Comment: In most cases purpose of `async-await` was for I/O operation (to free main thread while operation waiting response from I/O devices). In your case try to consider using `BackgroundWorker` with `ProgressChanged` on every loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official answer is that is depends on who calls your foo function. Is it the main thread, or could it be a different thread?

If it is the main thread (better: the thread that created the control), than you don't need an Invoke. Async does not influence this

The following is done by the UI thread, and will work fine.

```
public async void Button1_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
     await Foo();
}
```

Quite often people think that async-await is done by several threads. But in fact it is not. A thread in an async function performs all statements until it meets an await. Instead of really waiting until the awaited function completes, it goes up in its call stack to see if it can do something else.

This is perfectly explained in [Eric Lippert's restaurant metaphor](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1) (search on the page for async). Instead of waiting until the bread is toasted, the cook starts boiling eggs. But it is still the same cook.

When you see code where an async function is called without await, the thread will do the call until it meets an await and will perform the statements after the not-awaited call instead of doing nothing.

```
private async void Button1_clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    var taskFoo = this.Foo()
    // because not await: the thread will do the things in Foo until it meets
    // an await. Then it returns back to do the next statements:

    DoSomething();

    // if this function has nothing more to do, or if it needs the result
    // of Foo, await Foo:
    await taskFoo;

    ProcessFooResult();
}
```

This await for taskFoo has the effect control is given back to my caller (still the same thread), until my caller awaits. In that case control is given to his caller until await etc.

The only time a different thread is involved is when you actively start it, usually using:

```
var myTask = Task.Run( () => DoSomething() );
// Because there is no await, your thread will do immediately the next
// statements until an await:

DoOtherThings();
await myTask();
```

Now DoSomething is performed by a different thread. If you need to access UI controls you'll need InvokeRequired and Invoke.

Another helpful story about async-await: [Stephen Cleary about async-await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use `async` and `await` instead of creating a new Thread / BackgroundWorker.
In my opinion it is never bad to use Invoke when interacting with `Controls`.

Comment: Does't creating a new thread / backgroundWorker implies in running code on external thread then the need to use invoke? Even I think it's bad, I didn't find an alternative to Invoke when interacting with Controls

Comment: Yes, it does ...

by the way: `await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                foo();
            });`
is running not async?

Comment: If you use `await Task.Run(foo());` instead, it should block your UI and you **have to** use invoke.